# Where can I find images of mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-website

I've seen presentations given on mobile webapps which use a desktop browser, and an iframe containing the mobile app. Surrounding the iframe is an image of an iPhone or Android device, so it all basically looks like a simulator.

Where can I find images of mobile device 'bezels' that can be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best list I know: [Free Wireframing Kits, UI Design Kits, PDFs and Resources](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/27/free-wireframing-kits-ui-design-kits-pdfs-and-resources/)

They are mostly PSD and Omnigraffle files for both the iPhone and the Android.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple provides marketing resources](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/) to developers, in conjunction with [a required agreement](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/AppStoreMarketingLicense.pdf). This includes the "App Store badge" and device images.

Google supplies the Android "green robot" logo and has [guidelines as to the permitted usages](http://www.android.com/branding.html). I imagine Android device images are available from the manufacturers.

Comment: I've searched the Samsung website but haven't found anything for developers. The press kits seem to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Companies' web pages always have pictures of the devices they're trying to promote. And you can be sure that the images are very good ones.  That's where I get all my pics.

Answer (score 0):

You can download artwork of the devices from:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/

You need an Apple developer account.